# CSS Code isn't Working

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML as follows:

```css
.summary {
      top: 89%;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
    }

 section #summarypar1 {
      color: red;
      left: 15%;
      position: absolute;
      width: 70%;
    }

 section #summarypar2 {
      color: white;
      left: 15%;
      position: absolute;
      width: 70%;
    }
```

```html
   

 <section class="summary">

      <h1>Summary</h1>

      <p id="summarypar1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>


      <p id="summarypar2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

  </section>
```

This is the specific part where the output is wrong. Only the first paragraph gets the CSS effects, but not the second one.

I tried changing the  IDs into Classes and vice versa. I also tried writing "#summarypar1" instead of " section #summarypar1". Both these methods simply either made one of the two paragraphs or neither of them have the CSS effects.

So, I am thinking I am probably using the classes and or ID classifications incorrectly in my code. I read that it's better to be more specific (IDs) in CSS, but that doesn't help much.

Could I please get explanations of why this problem is happening?

Thank you,

Comment: your selectors are all wrong... no tags match

Comment: All three rulesets are being applied in the code you provided. The problem must be elsewhere. You need to supply a [mcve]

Comment: @Alexis could you please explain, because the section element gets the CSS outputs correctly?

Comment: @KhalidMukadam you can also use more than one class together. In my answer i used 2 classes for the paragraphs. I made a main one for paragraphs generally (with the margin-left and the width) and another for the color. When using 2 classes, you just put a space in between them like class="par p2"

Comment: @KhalidMukadam found two good links on css tricks (good website!) https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/ and https://css-tricks.com/little-css-stuff-newcomers-get-confused-about/ (good guide)  in your code you do have a summar css **class (.summary), but there is no summary id** (#summary). But an id will not inherit from a class, but a class will inherit properties from an id. The links are more informative. Did you run my code? If it works for you can you accept the answer– see https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer  (hover beside the answer and click - easy!)

Answer (score -1):

Because you don't have sections with the id summarypar1 and summarypar2.
Instead you have paragraphs with those id's.
So, it should be:

```
p#summarypar1{}
p#summarypar1{}
```

Comment: You seem to have missed the **descendant combinators** that appear between the `section` type selectors and the ID selectors.